# Difference between "{single_word"} and {single_word} searches on google docs

Tags: google-docs-api, google-drive-api

For some queries with documentlist api (and also within UI) I get different results for this queries:

```
1. "single_word"
2. single_word

For example for this: 
"mody" - I receive 69 results 
 mody  -  I receive >200 results (many of them don't contains this word)

(This happens also for combination of words that contains this word. For example:
**"mody" company** and **mody company** returns different results)
```

Which is the difference between this searches? And how it is recommanded to search for best exact matches results? I don't want to receive results that contains only **mod** (for example) words.

Answer (score 1):

"mody" matches tokens exactly with only the characters m-o-d-y, and whitespace on either side.  It only matches `mody`.

mody matches tokens containing the characters m-o-d-y.  It would match `mymody`, `mody`, `asdfmody`, `modyasdf`, etc.

Comment: The majority of results for **mody** query don't have tokens that contains m-o-d-y characters, they contains maximum **m-o-d** (without y)